# What can I do about illegal parking? Semi-peaceful protest, Scotland

Tags: united-kingdom, parking, scotland, protest

There are cars that park on the pavement on my street. It's been an issue for years. If there are bins out then the pavements can be unpassable for people walking and the pavement is always completely inaccessible for people using wheelchairs and prams.

I've gone to the police about it, not least because when I was forced onto the road last year I ended up getting clipped by a careless driver.

I've gone to the council and my locally elected representatives and nothing has been done.

I want to pose an inconvenience to these inconsiderate folks. I want to show them that what they're doing isn't ok. What examples of legal means of protest do I have that might stop a driver for a few moments and that would let them know that what they're doing is not ok. It is 100% illegal to park on the pavement where I live, so I do not feel bad about this.

There is plenty of room for everyone to park on the road. It's not that the street is too narrow that people can't park or the street ceases to function.

What if I was to put stickers on windshields? Is this legal? I've heard that sometimes "taggers" (graffiti "artists") put down a sticker because if the police confront them, they can simply remove the sticker and say "no harm, no foul".

This question is demonstrably not opinion based. I am asking for specific examples of peaceful protest against illegal parking!!

Comment: You said you have gone to the police, what was their response?  Parking tickets are both a source of revenue and a deterrent, enforcement works...

Comment: The police said they didn't have time to put out parking tickets. I spoke to parking enforcement but they said they couldn't do anything about pavement parking. They only enforce parking in restricted areas. But you can park on that street. It's just people are doing so improperly.

Comment: @MichaelHall Parking tickets (and other driving offences) aren’t a source of revenue for the police in the UK. Parking offences have been decriminalised to allow local councils rather than the police to keep the revenue from parking fines, and fines for criminal offences always go to the Treasury.

Comment: By "pavement", do you mean the sidewalk or the shoulder of the road?

Comment: By "pavement" I mean "pavement". I think you would call it a sidewalk.

Answer (score 1):

### Sue the owner(s) for nuisance

Sorry, I don’t know what the Scottish law equivalent is but if someone “f#&ks up your day” in England they have committed the tort of [nuisance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance_in_English_law).

You can initiate legal action and pursue nominal damages and force them into either defending themselves or conceding the matter.